# call a JS function inside an event method

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, mouseevent

I hope I'm not repeating a question but I've searched around and couldnt find help so I thought I should ask directly, I'm still a beginner and this is an assignment for my class so please be as thorough as possible

I'm trying to create a form where as the user clicks on another field, it checks if the input he put in the first one is as required by the website, without having to click enter or a submit button.

this is the HTML file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>  
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.ID").focusin(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFCC");
    });
    $("div.ID").focusout(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        userid_validation(userid,5,12);

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ID" >
  User ID: <input type="text" name="userid" size="12" />
 </div>

 <div class="pass">
 Password: <input type="text" name="psw" size="12" />
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the JS file

```
function userid_validation(userid,mx,my)  
{  
var uid_len = userid.value.length;  

if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx)  
{  

alert("User Id should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);  

//uid.focus();  
return false;  
}  

return true;  
}
```

I'm most probably doing something completely wrong but I don't know what. thanks in advance !

Comment: What exactly is the problem with that code?

Comment: Userid is undefined...

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't go to the function, I'm trying to make a message pop if the user entered wrong number of characters in the user ID field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `focusin` and `foucsout` on input elements. Currently you have applied it on `div`. Also you have code error on calling following function,

```
userid_validation(userid, 5, 12); // userid not defined.
```

Please check if this works.

```js
function userid_validation(userid, min, max) {
  var uid_len = userid.length;

  if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len > max || uid_len < min) {

    alert("User Id should not be empty / length be between " + min+ " to " + max);

    //uid.focus();  
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div.ID").find('input').focusin(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFCC");
      });
      $("div.ID").find('input').focusout(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        userid_validation($(this).val(), 5, 12);

      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="ID">
    User ID:
    <input type="text" name="userid" size="12" />
  </div>

  <div class="pass">
    Password:
    <input type="text" name="psw" size="12" />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it still doesnt check if the text input is between 5 and 12. no message pops out

Comment: @user3158009 check now. in your code you had used .length so it will not check for actual value. I have removed length so it will check for your actual content.

Comment: @user3158009 can you tell me what is your condition ? max, min?

Comment: nevermind it runs fine !
I'm using notepad++ and xampp local host to run it so the problem is probably in the application, thanks a lot

Comment: @user3158009 can you please try updated one. I have modified min max check of your code. Also it would motivating for me to answer if you accept my answer if that helped you.

Comment: just tired it, actually now it just pops up the message all the time, even if I enter an ID with 7 characters

Comment: @user3158009 try now. It was confusing whether you want to apply validation on actual value or lenght of the value. Now entire validation is on the length. Please do let me know

Comment: works perfectly ! thanks so much ^^ I clicked accept on your answer. thanks again

Comment: @user3158009 glad to help. Thanks.